# Weak contact on low voltage DC device causing noise. How?

Tags: power-supply, dc, noise

My laptop's DC power jack has a bad contact. And sometimes when the positions is just right, it makes a weird electrical noise which is about as loud as the laptops relatively quiet fans, clearly audible in a quiet room.

How can this weak/bad contact cause audible noise? Is this common in other scenarios?

Another interesting thing is that when I for example move the mouse, the noise changes pitch. I assume this is because of the increased power draw of the processor.

The noise only occurs when the contact isn't solid enough.

It is DC 19V with 4,7A max current and it has a ferrite ring very close to the DC jack.

Comment: It is probably arcing very slightly (a bad contact can do this if enough current is being drawn when the contact occurs). Is it the jack itself that makes the noise?

Comment: @LosFrijoles As far as I can tell, yes it is coming from the jack. I thought of arcing too. It surprises me if arcing is possible with 19VDC with such loads.

Comment: You can arc at very low voltage with enough current because the inductance of the power supply and power cable will cause the voltage to jump when it the current is suddenly interrupted. The relevant equation is V=L*di/dt where L is the inductance of the supply & power cable and di/dt is the change in current over time.

Comment: Is this a standard barrel connector?  If so, inspecting it with a magnifying glass /loupe should show you if it's arcing.  You'll see the carbonisation on the silvery metal.

Comment: What is the pitch of the noise? What can you compare it to?

Comment: @PaulUszak Similar to ceramic capacitors in cheap power supplies, just more varied. Also it seems it is heating up more than it should, so I think that is it. Visual inspection is hard, as the bad contacting part is in the inside of the barrel.

Comment: @LosFrijoles If you could post that as an answer explaining how can low voltage have such arcing, then I would accept that as an answer.

Comment: You can arc weld a ship's hull with a 35V welder so your PSU should be able to arc.  But, the pitch seems too high.  Arcing is a random process so I'd expect it to sound like white noise which is what an arc welder sounds like.  Curious.

Answer (score 1):

It's arcing, low-voltage sparking, creates heat and the air expands... result, noise.

You have a bad contact, possibly a broken solder joint.   It generates
heat as a result, and could cause serious damage.  So, best to repair it,
or get it repaired.    Jiggling it will make things worse, because
the parts may overheat AND come under stress at the same time.

Comment: Ok, but the question is specifically how this can cause a noise

Comment: Arcing, low-voltage sparking, creates heat and the air expands... result, noise.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your answer with that information. As it stands, it doesn't answer the question and could end up being deleted.